# Handling errors with Spring Cloud stream and Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

In version [4.0.x of the Spring Cloud stream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_handle_error_messages) with Spring Boot 3 it seems that the way in which errors can be handled has been changed compared to version [3.2.0 of SCS via the commonErrorHandlerBeanName](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.2.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties) property in the binding.

However, with Spring Cloud Stream version 4.0.x, error handling using the `commonErrorHandlerBeanName` property in the Consumer properties still works correctly, although this form of error handling is no longer in the documentation for the latest version of SCS and [is no longer deprecated at the code level](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/blob/4.x/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kafka/KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java#L791-L796)...

What is the appropriate way to handle errors in SCS for future versions, and what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Both error-handling mechanisms should work. While the new [error handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_handle_error_messages) you mentioned from `4.0.x` is added as a general error handling technique regardless of the underlying binder. With Kafka binder, you still have the flexibility (and more appropriate, depending on your use case) of using [commonErrorHandlerBeanName](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties). This latter method is not deprecated in the Kafka binder, and neither there are any plans to do so in the future.